# How to set height of all textboxes be equal size in an report? - Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm working on an existing report created using Crystal Reports.

In this report, a new column was added, but, the value of the column/row surpasses the default design of the report.

> **NOTE**: The following example is in the "Details section" of the report
>   and is equivalent of the rows of a table.

Example:

```
 ____________________________ 
| Name      | Worker type    |  // (Worker type) is the new column
|___________|________________|
|  Item 1   | Text 1         |  // Row 1
|  Item 2   | Text 2         | 
|___________| Text 3         |    
|  Item 3   | Text 4         |  
|  Item 4   |________________|
|___________| Text 2         |  // Row 2 - might be bigger "height" than "Name" column.
|  Item 5   | Text 1         |
|  Item 6   | Text 2         |
|___________|________________|
```

The desired rendered result is:

```
 ____________________________   
| Name      | Worker type    |  // (Worker type) is the new column
|___________|________________|
|  Item 1   | Text 1         |  // Row 1
|  Item 2   | Text 2 Text 3  | 
|___________|________________|    
|  Item 3   | Text 4         |  // Row 2  
|  Item 4   |                |
|───────────|────────────────|
|  Item 5   | Text 2         |  // Row 3 - all rows / columns has appropiate design size.
|  Item 5   | Text 1         |
|  Item 6   | Text 2         |
|___________|________________|
```

I had tried:

1. Removing box objects: the original report uses them for set a black border on the "details section" - resulting in the example above.
2. By removing the box objects, I set the border of the data fields - or textboxes - directly. This leads to border lines didn't increase/expand to the next row.

Example of the modification made - described in the point # 2 - not consistent design:

```
 ____________________________ 
| Name      | Worker type    |  // (Worker type) is the new column
|___________|________________|
|  Item 1   | Text 1         |  // Row 1
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
|  Item 2   | Text 2         |  // Row 2
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯ 
|  Text 3   | Text 3         |  // Row 3  
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯           
|  Item 4   |                |
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
|  Item 5   | Text 1         |
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
|  Item 6   | Text 2         |
|___________|________________|
```

3. Use the "Can Grow" option for each datafield - no results adjusting the size of the other columns to be the same as the "Worker type" new column.
4. Search on internet and here, in Stack Overflow: no results so far.

I don't know how to proceed for set the same size for all datafields/textboxes in the report.

Is there a way to set all files to have equal size in Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After search deeper in both Google and in Stack Overflow (*and honestly, after a weekend break*), I found the solution:

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20697974/12511801) says:

> Do not use borders of text box to make cell borders, **instead use lines
>   to create borders one horizontal line above the text boxes and one
>   below the text boxes. both lines having width long as the detail
>   section. and for vertical borders use vertical lines. that starts from
>   top of group header section and ends at bottom of detail section. now
>   when the height of cell increases when the content is large then all
>   the rows will be set accordingly**.

This this in mind, I have to use the "Line Object" and draw the lines that divides the rows, then, by selecting the lines drawn and press "**Format Multiple Objects**", I marked/checked these two options on the Line - Format Editor window:

- Extend to Bottom of section when Printing
- Repeat on Horizontal Pages

I think the first one is the one who makes the "magic" - i.e, extending the line, but, just to be sure, the second option should be marked too.

After these changes, I did get the desired result:

```
 ____________________________   
| Name      | Worker type    |  // (Worker type) is the new column
|___________|________________|
|  Item 1   | Text 1         |  // Row 1
|  Item 2   | Text 2 Text 3  | 
|___________|________________|    
|  Item 3   | Text 4         |  // Row 2  
|  Item 4   |                |
|───────────|────────────────|
|  Item 5   | Text 2         |  // Row 3 - now all rows / columns has appropiate design size.
|  Item 5   | Text 1         |
|  Item 6   | Text 2         |
|___________|________________|
```